# How to map from one model to another in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this function in my Angular 2 component, which calls Web Api:

```
getNextConjunctionApi(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this.uri + '/GetNextConjunction')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Web Api returns a complex object, which I would like to map to an Angular 2 model called ClientModel:

```
export class ClientModel {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    ...
}
```

Can this mapping be done by rewriting the map functionality, or need I do it in some other way?

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: Do you mean how to get data from a service to a component? If so then yes in your service you do the mapping and you get that data in a component by subscribing to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this with a slightly different approach.  I had my component call a service that would return an observable.  My component could then use a specific type that I created.  I will show you what I have done for a blog.

posts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from './posts.service';
import { PostComponent } from '../post/post.component';  // --> This is my custom type
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  providers: [PostsService]
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Observable<PostComponent[]>;  // --> I use the type here

  constructor( private _postsService: PostsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._postsService.getAllPosts()
      .subscribe( 
        posts => { this.posts = posts },  // -->  I add the return values here
        error => { console.log(error) }
      );
  }
}
```

The above has three key pieces.  I import the custom type, `PostComponent`, set `posts` to an Observable of type `PostComponent` array, and as the Observable comes back, I add the values to the `posts` array.

posts.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {

  constructor( private _http: Http ) {}

  getAllPosts(){
    return this._http.get('[INSERT API CALL]')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(msg => Observable.throw(msg));
  }
}
```

In my service, I only map the response to `response.json`.  This gives me more information than I need.  I 'filter' it in my `post.component`

post.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html'
})
export class PostComponent{  
  @Input() curPost: {
    'id': number,
    'title': string,
    'author': string,
    'date': string,
    'body' : string,
  };

  constructor() { }
}
```